# How does C/C++ copy structs?

Tags: c++, c, struct, copy

When passing a struct in C/C++ by value the struct contents must be copied. How do compilers achieve that? I.e., which assembly instructions are usually emitted for this copy?

How fast are these, when, e.g. compared to a call to memcpy?

Now consider this code:

```
struct X { int i, j, k; };

void foo(X x);

void foo( int i, int j, int k);
```

Is there any difference between calling foo(X) and foo(int,int,int) or might the generated assembly code be the same (considering the passing of parameters)?

Comment: Why don't you profile it and find out?

Comment: All compilers support options to generate assembly files instead of object files. Use that and look at the assembly yourself. Also, if the compiler actually does a copy or not can depend on optimizations.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore: Because my profiling results might only be true for my machine or my compiler. I guess somebody with a deeper knowledge is a better source here than my profiling.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg: Then again, this is only true for my compiler and my code. It might be possible that with another compiler totally different code is generated. Therefore, I want to know this from somebody who understands the details behind this process, not from a test that just tries it without knowing WHY these instructions are generated.

Comment: If you want a general answer that is valid for all platforms and all compilers, you will not get any. The only thing you can do is check how it works for you, for your program, on your platform using your compiler.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg: Of course I dont want an answer like "Every platform uses MOV". I know that I cannot get an answer like that. However, there could be an answer like "The compiler is free to do everything possible to create the copy. However, most compilers will use XXX (if the platform supports it) because it is fastest and this is equal to doing YYY", for example.

Comment: Isn't that what you're interested in? Results for your platform/compiler?

Comment: @Luchian Grigore: No, I am seeking more general knowledge :)

Comment: @gexicide: Ok, so provide some compilable test cases, using clever measuring methods and distribute it ... as for example as part of you question at SO, which also includes thoughts about the results you already observed. I'm sure you could provoke a discussion such way ... ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously, if there is a constructor for the `struct` or `class`, then the constructor is called.

If there isn't a constructor, it is entirely up to the compiler, but most likely, for three integer sized objects, it will probably be three individual `mov` instructions. For larger structures, it's either a call to `memcpy` or an inlined version similar to `memcpy`.

It is also quite likely that if the structure is VERY large (several megabytes), that true `memcpy` is faster than the inlined version, and the compiler may not realize this and use the inlined version anyway. But most of us don't use megabytes large structs, so I don't think generally that's something to worry too much about. Copying structs onto the stack as arguments, if the struct is megabytes large, is probably not a great idea in the first place, given the restricted size of a typical stack.

Answer (score 6):

### In C++

> **How do compilers achieve that?**

They call the **copy constructor** for that class/structure. The implicitly generated one if you don't provide one or the one you provide.

> **How fast are these, when, e.g. compared to a call to `memcpy`?**

Depends on the class and its members. Profiling should give you a clearer picture.
However, using `memcpy` to copy class instances should be avoided.

### In C

> **How do compilers achieve that?**

They perform a **[shallow copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy#Shallow_copy)** for that structure. For all practical purposes you can consider it same as `memcpy`.

Comment: And in C? And in an automatically generated copy constructor in C++?

Comment: I know that they perform a shallow copy. But how is that one implemented.

Comment: @gexicide However the compiler sees fit in the particular case. Though, for e.g. a bunch of `int`s it would be quite stupid to use a general `memcpy`, and you can (usually) assume your compiler to not be that stupid.

Answer (score 3):

There are two distint cases.

- If your struct is [**POD**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c), the copy is optimized and will be as fast as memcpy (with proper optimization level).
- If your struct is **not POD**, C++ has to call the copy constructor for your object. The copy constructor may call other functions, new operators, etc. so it will be slower than memcpy. But `memcpy` will not copy the struct correcty, using `memcpy` on a non-POD type results in undefined behaviour!

Note that e.g. in `g++` the call to `memcpy` will be inlined and optimized out. As the intention between a struct copy and a memcpy call is exactly the same (copy X bytes from location Y to Z), I do not think that the generated assembly code will differ.

Anyway, to be sure, find it out by analyzing the assembly of your code.

---

Edit: just read the end of the question about the function parameters. Please note that function parameter passing is usually (especially in x64) done in registers and it is much faster than `memcpy`.

I've checked the assembly code and they **do differ**. The exact code will depend on the [calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) your current compiler uses. For me the struct is not passed in registers, rather it's passed on the stack and an actual copy is made. The three `int`s are passed in `%ecx`, `%edx` and `%r8d`. I've tried this on Windows GCC. It seems to use the Windows x64 calling convetion.

For more information on how the parameters are passed look at the specifications of your calling convention. All the details and corner cases are worked out. E.g. for x64 GCC look at System V AMD64 ABI Chapter 3.2.3 Parameter passing. For Visual Studio look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthk2dkh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Very interesting. This means that the struct version should be really slower in the function parameter case. Why does the compiler miss this easy chance for optimization?

Comment: The compiler cannot really optimize here. It is written in stone (in the calling convention specifications) how to call a function, so the compiler just adheres to the specification. This allows two functions in different translation units to be linked together. (I'm talking about non-inline functions of course.)

Comment: Is it also written in stone that ints have to be passed in registers? What if I doesn't have that many registers?

Comment: @gexicide That is a big stone with many rules :) Google "System V AMD64 ABI" and look for chapter 3.2.3 Parameter passing. I think the official link is down, but there are many mirrors.

Answer (score 0):

See another answer by [Alok Save](https://stackoverflow.com/users/452307/alok-save) for [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). In [c](/questions/tagged/c), it can be `memcpy` (or equivalent) or an inlined version of it (up to one `mov` instuction for structures with a good size).